# Bash alias based on conditional

Tags: linux, bash

I want to create a bash alias called `pg` to use a pager program based on a condition. The condition is: If `most` is present then use it, otherwise use `less`. This is what I have so far:

```
alias pg='command -v most &> /dev/null && most $1 || less $1'
```

... but when I use it like this `pg .gitconfig` for instance I get `most` usage output:

```
MOST version 5.0.0 (S-Lang version 2.3.2)
Usage:
most [-1Cbcdkstvw] [+/string] [+line number] [+s] [+d] file...
 where: -1:  assume VT100 terminal. (VMS only)
        -b:  Startup in binary mode.
...
```

At least the condition is working correctly. But what am I missing to get the pager to actually display the file contents?

Comment: [In Bash, when to alias, when to script, and when to write a function?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/30925/108618) An alias replaces text with text. Take `pg .gitconfig` and *literally* replace `pg` with `command -v most &> /dev/null && most $1 || less $1`. Note `$1` appears as `$1`. Any logic or expansion will be performed *later*. This is what your alias does. Use a function instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree with Kamil Maciorowki's recommendation to use a function, but if you really want to use an alias, this works:

```
alias pg='command -v most &> /dev/null && _pg=most || _pg=less; $_pg'
```

The problem with the original syntax is that when the alias is expanded, there is no real way to differentiate to the shell between the command and the argument. My proposed solution is clumsy but it works.

The only caveat is that if the variable `$_pg` already exists in the environment, invoking this alias will clobber it. This could be prevented with a collision-checking conditional, or maybe even using a dynamically named random variable, or both...

But rather than raising the fanciness to 11, I second Kamil and recommend using a function instead of an alias in this case.